# replacing with image with color to make my application faster

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-transitions

- I have a div with `background-image` property attached to it
- I wanted to replace the background image with `css` color
- I added the `background-color` but don't know how to make the rounded corner and make it to occupy only half of the container
- I am replacing with image with color to make my application faster

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Providing my code below. I am attaching the screenshot too[image]

```
<span class="position-ind all-values">
    <div class="color-ind">--outer container
        <div class="all-values-light"/></div>--inner container
    </div>


.gen-position-green-row .all-values .all-values-light{
        /*background-image: url('../img/positionIndicator_glow.png');*/
        background-color: white;
        border: solid 1px;
      /* the border will curve into a 'D' */  
      border-radius: 10px 40px 40px 10px;
    }
```

Comment: `border-radius` is the property you set to give rounded edges, but when doing this it adds complexity to the render, if you add too much CSS it can actually take longer to render than an image.

Comment: @Jasper: thanks for ur reply...can u edit it in my code

Comment: Here are some great docs for `border-radius`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: edited my code but still not working

Comment: Did you notice the "Browser Compatibility" section? Depending on the browser you're using, you may need `-webkit-` or `-moz-` prefixes on `border-radius`.

Comment: @Jasper: thanks for your reply what about ie8 browsers

Comment: Check-out http://www.caniuse.com/. It'll break-down the compatibility with a lot of stuff by browser and version.